# How much can a bash script interact with a running web browser?

Tags: bash, monitoring, browser, application, real-time

Here is what I have so far:

- initiate when a web browser is running
- download all content from current webpage and scan for "content of interest"
- output summary/details of said "content of interest"

but I can only get this output into a file to the screen. This is something that I've kept completely within cli, and I believe this may be about as far as I can take it. Am I wrong here?

I want to be able to interact with the browser somewhat like an extension/add-on would do. What method or routes known can be of use to model my project?

Comment: I have some experience with creating a "bot" using a CLI tools, But what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: If you want to interact like and extension/add-on why don't you create that? The way I would do any interaction with a web page (not the browser) from a script would be using `wget`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use bash for this, but the controlling of some browsers can be done via extending the pages with (extra) JavaScript and bash could communicate with that.

Instead of developing such a web browser driver from scratch (and not wanting to delve deeper in JavaScript than I have already done), I have gone with [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and a custom program (in my case in Python) that reads commands from files in a predetermined directory. The commands are text files and are written by other programs (bash, python, but could be anything) that can schedule single actions and repeated actions, background tasks (if nothing else is scheduled to be done). For new, unforeseen tasks, the custom program must be adapted and the web browser restarted, but after the initial development phase such extensions were seldom necessary.